# How to connect 2 PCs via ssh client using a server?

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have 2 PCs that I want to connect over the internet with a ssh port forward. The problem is that both PCs dont have a public IP. My Idea was to use a public server (ps) and use `ssh -R <port>:localhost:<port> <ps-user>@<ps-address>` on PC1.

For PC2 I tried 2 things to create a Connection to PC1:  `ssh -p <port> <pc1-user>@<ps-address>` and `ssh -L <port>:localhost:<port> <pc1-user>@<ps-address>`. But both do not result in an ssh connection to PC1.

What do I do wrong here?

Addition: Please note that I can not port forward on both PC1 and PC2

Comment: You may use the router's public IP, but only for connecting from outside the network (no round trips), setting up port forwarding on the router. Otherwise, your post is very unclear - could you substitute values for `<port>` etc. and report on your operating systems and local network architecture?

Comment: Sure, the Port is 5900. The background is that I have a ubuntu device (PC1) that is in an unknown network (the device travels from location to location, most of the time it will just be a single router + the device in the network but I have no way to configure the router to forward a port for me). I want to be able to establish a encrypted vnc session using ssh and x11vnc from any Windows PC (PC2, this one also changes the location but is never in the same lan as PC1) to the device PC1 (PC1 is running x11vnc).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if I understood your question, you have:

- 2 PCs on internal networks.
- You have no influence on the routers on either network.

And you want to:

- Set up a public server (**PS**) hosting an SSH service (I assume **port 22**).
- Connect **PC1** and **PC2** to **PS** (Outgoing traffic, no router config).
- Connect a VNC session from **PC2** (Windows) to **PC1** (Ubuntu) on port **5900**.

You can achieve that by creating an SSH tunnel, doing a remote forwarding from PC1 and a local forwarding from PC2.

This would be the architecture:[image: Architecture diagram]

So to get this working, from the Ubuntu PC, PC1, you need to connect to PS using:

```
ssh <ps-user>@<ps-address> -R 5901:localhost:5900
```

At this point if you logged into the PC1 you may run `netstat -latn | grep 5901` and you should see it listening. This means that one half of the process is ready.

Now the client connection. From PC2, if it was a linux box too, you might use

```
ssh <ps-user>@<ps-address> -L 5902:localhost:5901
```

if it is Windows, you can use PuTTY, by setting the port forwarding section below `Connection` / `SSH` / `Tunnels`, and add a Local port with Source port `5902` and destination `localhost:5901`. When clicking add you will see in the list of forwarded ports something like `L5902  localhost:5901`

Now you have two tunnels connected to a public server. If you run VNC viewer from PC2 and point to localhost:5902, you should connect to the VNC service listening on port 5900 on PC1.

Hope it helps.